# Character more than once in string

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I check if character shows up in a variable more than once in crystal syntax?

```
Global Stringvar ticketnum;
if InStr(ticketnum,',') > 0 then
```

This gives me the placement of the comma, but not if it shows up more than once

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if InStr(ticketnum,',') > 0 then ubound(split(ticketnum','))-1
```